# FileNotFoundException in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel i am making an application that uploads a file and the user can download that same file.

But each time i click to upload i get this error.

```
 FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37: The file
 "H:\wamp64\tmp\phpF040.tmp" does not exist
```

my view code is this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@inject('Kala','App\Kala')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
 @include('common.errors')
        <form action="/addkala" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="text" name="details">
            <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" >
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

and my controller

```
public function addkalapost(Request $request)
{


     $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'details' => 'required',
   'photo' => 'max:1024',
];
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
if($v->fails()){

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors())->withInput($request->except('photo'));

} else {


    $file = $request->file('photo');

        $fileName = time().'_'.$request->name;
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads';

        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    $kala=new Kala;

        $kala->name=$request->name;
          return 1;    
    $kala->details=$request->details;

    $kala->pic_name=$fileName;

        $kala->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'The post successfully inserted.');

}



}
```

and i change the upload max size in php.ini to 1000M.
plz help 
im confusing

Comment: Did you check the uploaded file was `->Valid`

Comment: $fileName = time().'_'.$request->name; Change this to $fileName = time().'_'.$request->file('photo');

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you using filesystems for that by default the folder is storage/app you need to get file from there
if your file is located somewhere else you can make your own disk in config/filesystems e.g. `'myDisk' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' =>base_path('xyzFolder'),
        ],`

and you can call it like

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$data = Storage::disk('myDisk')->get('myFile.txt');
```

this is obviously to get file and you can perform any other function by following laravel docs.